# Why the people go for mobile-first approch, rather than Desktop first approach?

Tags: mobile, responsive

I see so many people are going for mobile-first approach rather than desktop first.Anyways we have to do mobile responsiveness to be good using media queries or some responsive frameworks(if i need mobile responsive website).Even i choose desktop-first approach. why the people has started the term mobile-first approach and they are using it.

Comment: Because people carry a mobile with them :). If you write a slick app for mobile it works great on Desktop and it does not work in other direction.

Comment: if we create desktop first app also, we can create mobile responsive app to work great in mobile right?

Comment: Try creating a responsive app and see how it loads in a mobile browser. Use a actual device. Check it on PC by using changing window size does not work because mobile processors are not fast. If you go your way, you will drain your mobile battery in few minutes without any resonable value to the user.

Comment: Thank you. i got the answer now. But now a days some laptops have some 1.6Ghz of processor and mobile have 2.2Ghz processor right

Comment: You can't look at some laptops(esp. chromebooks) and some mobiles. If you do so, you will miss the majority of the market.